# Retrofit: how to parse GZIP'd response without Content-Encoding: gzip header

Tags: gzip, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm trying to process a server response which is GZIP'd. The response comes with a header

```
Content-Type: application/x-gzip
```

but does not have header

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

If I add that header using a proxy, the response gets parsed just fine.
I don't have any control over the server, so I can't add the header.

Can I force Retrofit to treat it as GZIP content? Is there a better way?
The URL for the server is:
http://crowdtorch.cms.s3.amazonaws.com/4474/Updates/update-1.xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a better way than reinventing the wheel. Just add the `Content-Encoding` header yourself.

```
.addNetworkInterceptor((Interceptor.Chain chain) -> {
    Request req = chain.request();
    Headers.Builder headersBuilder = req.headers().newBuilder();

    String credential = Credentials.basic(...);
    headersBuilder.set("Authorization", credential);

    Response res = chain.proceed(req.newBuilder().headers(headersBuilder.build()).build());

    return res.newBuilder()
        .header("Content-Encoding", "gzip")
        .header("Content-Type", ""application/json")
        .build();
})
```

In fact, your code is a classic example of the evils of using internal code (like `com.sun` packages from the JDK). `RealResponseBody` doesn't have that constructor anymore.

Comment: Interesting. Use an interceptor. Good idea. Sounds like it ought to work.

Comment: @itsymbal it does, I use it

Answer (score 12):

I figured it out. The idea is to add a custom interceptor which will take the not-yet-unzipped response, and unzip it 'manually' - do the same thing that OkHttp would do automatically based on Content-Encoding header, but without requiring that header.

is like dis:

```
    OkHttpClient.Builder clientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(new UnzippingInterceptor());
    OkHttpClient client = clientBuilder.build();
```

And the Interceptor is like dis:

```
private class UnzippingInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
        return unzip(response);
    }
}
```

And the unzip function is like dis:

```
    // copied from okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine (because is private)
private Response unzip(final Response response) throws IOException {

    if (response.body() == null) {
        return response;
    }

    GzipSource responseBody = new GzipSource(response.body().source());
    Headers strippedHeaders = response.headers().newBuilder()
            .removeAll("Content-Encoding")
            .removeAll("Content-Length")
            .build();
    return response.newBuilder()
            .headers(strippedHeaders)
            .body(new RealResponseBody(strippedHeaders, Okio.buffer(responseBody)))
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with gzip files:

```
private fun decompressGzip(responseBody: ResponseBody): String {
    try {
        // Create a GZIPInputStream to decompress the data
        val gzipInputStream = GZIPInputStream(responseBody.byteStream())

        // Use a ByteArrayOutputStream to hold the decompressed data
        val byteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()

        // Buffer for reading data
        val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
        var bytesRead: Int

        // Read from the GZIPInputStream and write to the ByteArrayOutputStream
        while (gzipInputStream.read(buffer).also { bytesRead = it } != -1) {
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
        }

        // Convert the ByteArrayOutputStream to a byte array
        val decompressedData = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()

        // Optionally convert the byte array to a string or other format as needed
        return String(decompressedData, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        // Handle exceptions
    }

    return ""
}

fun getGzip(
    country: String,
    onRadioMutableListGetCallback: OnRadioListGetCallback
) {
    val call = apiServiceBackup.MutableListByCountryBackup(
        country.toLowerCase(),
    )
    call.enqueue(object : Callback<ResponseBody> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseBody>, response: Response<ResponseBody>) {
            val res = response.body() ?: return
            val json = decompressGzip(res)
            val gson = Gson()
            val myObjectListType = object : TypeToken<List<RadioData>>() {}.type
            val stations = gson.fromJson<MutableList<RadioData>>(json, myObjectListType)
            onRadioMutableListGetCallback.onRadioListGet(stations)
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseBody>, t: Throwable) {
            onRadioMutableListGetCallback.onRadioListGet(ArrayList())
        }
    })
}

    @GET("{country}.json.gz")
    fun MutableListByCountryBackup(
        @Path("country") user: String?
    ): Call<ResponseBody>
```