# Android - OKHttp: how to enable gzip for POST

Tags: android, nginx, retrofit, gzip, okhttp

In our Android App, I'm sending pretty large files to our (NGINX) server so I was hoping to use gzip for my Retrofit **POST** message.

There are many documentations about OkHttp using gzip transparently or changing the headers in order to accept gzip (i.e. in a **GET** message).

But how can I enable this feature for **sending gzip http POST messages** from my device?
Do I have to write a custom Intercepter or something? Or simply add something to the headers?

Comment: I found the source for a GzipRequestInterceptor here: https://insight.io/github.com/square/okhttp/blob/HEAD/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/RequestBodyCompression.java?line=73
Is this what I need?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to the following [recipe](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/7135628c645892faf1a48a8cff464e0ed4ad88cb/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/RequestBodyCompression.java): 
The correct flow for gzip would be something like this:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
      .addInterceptor(new GzipRequestInterceptor())
      .build();

/** This interceptor compresses the HTTP request body. Many webservers can't handle this! */
  static class GzipRequestInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    @Override public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
      Request originalRequest = chain.request();
      if (originalRequest.body() == null || originalRequest.header("Content-Encoding") != null) {
        return chain.proceed(originalRequest);
      }

      Request compressedRequest = originalRequest.newBuilder()
          .header("Content-Encoding", "gzip")
          .method(originalRequest.method(), gzip(originalRequest.body()))
          .build();
      return chain.proceed(compressedRequest);
    }

    private RequestBody gzip(final RequestBody body) {
      return new RequestBody() {
        @Override public MediaType contentType() {
          return body.contentType();
        }

        @Override public long contentLength() {
          return -1; // We don't know the compressed length in advance!
        }

        @Override public void writeTo(BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {
          BufferedSink gzipSink = Okio.buffer(new GzipSink(sink));
          body.writeTo(gzipSink);
          gzipSink.close();
        }
      };
    }
  }
```

Comment: Okay, so it is what I assumed from the OkHttp samples. Thanks for the affirmation!

Comment: @Jason This approach fails in my case with due to Transfer-Encoding: chunked. I can not set content length as -1

Comment: This works, thanks. FYI:
1. Add this intercepter using addInterceptor() not addNetworkInterceptor()
2. Retrofit automatically handles 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' header i.e. for decompression of gzipped response. You don't need to worry about it.
3. On the other hand, you'd need to add the above GzipRequestInterceptor() to send gzipped request

Comment: You may not want to compress every single request body since small request bodies are likely end up larger, see https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31750/what-is-recommended-minimum-object-size-for-gzip-performance-benefits

Comment: @Leanid Vouk I tried your solution but unfortunately the response body is omitted from the log of http logging interceptor but I tried to log the request body by myself but the compression text was so weird.

Original request body: {"data":{"lng":"-122.0840926","lat":"37.4219524"},"device_id":"XXXXX"}
Compressed request body: ���������������9
� �����ڈ�h.�\� �$�x���L�0��D��x��������=���ኤӤ��r�Z*w�{D�A��J�ՒNX?��r�Q������

So why do you think this is happening?

Comment: @AshrafAtef this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78073801/1604309

Answer (score 2):

in addition to the accepted answer: First, declare this class (from @Jason)

```
// to compress the body of request which is injected as interceptor.
public class GzipInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    @Override public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request originalRequest = chain.request();

        // do not set content encoding in negative use case

        if (originalRequest.body() == null || originalRequest.header("Content-Encoding") != null) {
            return chain.proceed(originalRequest);
        }

        Request compressedRequest = originalRequest.newBuilder()
                .header("Content-Encoding", "gzip")
                .method(originalRequest.method(), gzip(originalRequest.body()))
                .build();
        return chain.proceed(compressedRequest);
    }

    private RequestBody gzip(final RequestBody body) {
        return new RequestBody() {
            @Override public MediaType contentType() {
                return body.contentType();
            }

            @Override public long contentLength() {
                return -1; // We don't know the compressed length in advance!
            }

            @Override public void writeTo(BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {
                BufferedSink gzipSink = Okio.buffer(new GzipSink(sink));
                body.writeTo(gzipSink);
                gzipSink.close();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

then :

```
 //Encryption Interceptor
GzipInterceptor gzipInterceptor = new GzipInterceptor();

// OkHttpClient. Be conscious with the order
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient()
        .newBuilder()
        //httpLogging interceptor for logging network requests
        .addInterceptor(gzipInterceptor)
        .build();
```

Finally add it to your retrofit as a client: (No need for further changes!)

```
 Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .baseUrl(Constants.serveraddress)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();
Serverinterface serverinterface = retrofit.create(Serverinterface.class);
```

Comment: In order to report `contentLength` look that the implementation of the `forceContentLength` method [here](https://gist.github.com/xsobolx/e40b4cc8d8b9d36fb7a0a08b94268db3)