# Java Okhttp3 "Please enable JS and disable any ad blocker"

Tags: java, retrofit, okhttp

I am trying to get a request to get the json file but once i do that I get the Log that i get is that it doesn't see the json file. infact, it only sees the Log below.

Should i get another response than this in order to get the info of the Json file?

This is the link i want to get a request from:
https://www.footlocker.nl/INTERSHOP/static/FLE/Footlocker-Site/-/Footlocker/%22%20+%20%22en_US/Release-Calendar/Launchcalendar/launchdata/launchcalendar_feed_all.json

```
jan. 10, 2021 11:26:59 P.M. okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform log
INFO: <html><head><title>footlocker.nl</title><style>#cmsg{animation: A 1.5s;}@keyframes A{0%{opacity:0;}99%{opacity:0;}100%{opacity:1;}}</style></head><body style="margin:0"><p id="cmsg">Please enable JS and disable any ad blocker</p><script>var dd={'cid':'AHrlqAAAAAMA_bz9MUAng5wAUHCDZw==','hsh':'A55FBF4311ED6F1BF9911EB71931D5','t':'fe','s':17434,'host':'geo.captcha-delivery.com'}</script><script src="https://ct.captcha-delivery.com/c.js"></script></body></html>
```

And this is my code:

```
public FootlockerV2() {
    tester();
}

public void tester() {
    
    var loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    //httpClient maken.
    OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

    httpClient.addInterceptor(chain -> {

        Request request = chain.request();
        Request.Builder newRequest = request.newBuilder()
                .header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 " +
                        "(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36")
                .header("authority", "www.footlocker.nl")
                .header("scheme", "https")
                .header("cache-control", "no-cache")
                .header("path", "/INTERSHOP/static/FLE/Footlocker-Site/-/Footlocker/%22%20+%20%22en_US/Release-Calendar/Launchcalendar/launchdata/launchcalendar_feed_all.json")
                .header("accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9");

        return chain.proceed(newRequest.build());
    }).addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor);

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()

            .client(httpClient.build())
            .baseUrl(Api.base)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    Api api = retrofit.create(Api.class);


    Call<List<Article>> call = api.getArticles();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Article>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Article>> call, Response<List<Article>> response) {


            List<Article> articles = response.body();

            if (articles != null) {
                for (Article article : articles) {

                    System.out.println(response.body().toString());
                    System.out.println(article.getName() + "\n");
                }
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Article>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });

}`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dealing with such response is more or less trivial, and usually follows the following pattern:

#### Copy the generated `curl` command

Open the network request in the debugger Network tab (assuming you're on Google Chrome/Chromium if I've parsed the `User-Agent` header properly), and copy it using the "Copy as cURL" menu item. Once it's copied, double-check the generated command works well in the terminal.

#### Trim off unnecessary parameters from the `curl` command

I usually create a quick small git repo for such experiments, where I commit every successful step, and first put the command to an executable bash script to run it quickly. The more you trim, the smaller the `curl` command becomes, so that you have as small `curl` command as possible. Here is what I got:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

curl 'https://www.footlocker.nl/INTERSHOP/static/FLE/Footlocker-Site/-/Footlocker/%22%20+%20%22en_US/Release-Calendar/Launchcalendar/launchdata/launchcalendar_feed_all.json' \
    -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36' \
    -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
    --compressed
```

This is the *smallest* viable command for your request. Now enable the `-v` switch so that you could inspect what `curl` actually sends to the server:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

curl -v 'https://www.footlocker.nl/INTERSHOP/static/FLE/Footlocker-Site/-/Footlocker/%22%20+%20%22en_US/Release-Calendar/Launchcalendar/launchdata/launchcalendar_feed_all.json' \
    -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36' \
    -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
    --compressed
```

You could see something like:

```
> GET /INTERSHOP/static/FLE/Footlocker-Site/-/Footlocker/%22%20+%20%22en_US/Release-Calendar/Launchcalendar/launchdata/launchcalendar_feed_all.json HTTP/2
> Host: www.footlocker.nl
> Accept: */*
> Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
> user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36
> accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

Since you seem to use a Windows system, you don't necessarily need `bash`, `cmd` should be fine, but make sure Chrome/Chromium generates a `cmd`-compatible `curl` command.

#### Translate the `curl` request pattern to the Retrofit interceptor

Note that it does not work without `--compressed` that is actually mapped to `Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip`.

[okhttp 3: how to decompress gzip/deflate response manually using Java/Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51901333/okhttp-3-how-to-decompress-gzip-deflate-response-manually-using-java-android)

```java
final class GunzipRequestInterceptor
        implements Interceptor {

    private static final Interceptor instance = new GunzipRequestInterceptor();

    private GunzipRequestInterceptor() {
    }

    static Interceptor getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public Response intercept(final Chain chain)
            throws IOException {
        return gunzip(chain.proceed(chain.request()));
    }

    private static Response gunzip(final Response response) {
        if ( response.body() == null ) {
            return response;
        }
        final String contentEncoding = response.headers().get("Content-Encoding");
        if ( !contentEncoding.equals("gzip") ) {
            return response;
        }
        final Headers headers = response.headers().newBuilder().build();
        final ResponseBody body = new RealResponseBody(headers, Okio.buffer(new GzipSource(response.body().source())));
        return response.newBuilder()
                .headers(headers)
                .body(body)
                .build();
    }

}
```

```java
interface IFootLockerClient {

    @GET("/INTERSHOP/static/FLE/Footlocker-Site/-/Footlocker/\"%20+%20\"en_US/Release-Calendar/Launchcalendar/launchdata/launchcalendar_feed_all.json")
    Call<JsonElement> get();

}
```

```java
final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://www.footlocker.nl/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(GunzipRequestInterceptor.getInstance())
                .addInterceptor(chain -> chain.proceed(chain.request()
                        .newBuilder()
                        .header("Accept", "*/*")
                        .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip")
                        .header("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9")
                        .header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36")
                        .build()
                ))
                .build()
        )
        .build();
final IFootLockerClient client = retrofit.create(IFootLockerClient.class);
final Call<JsonElement> jsonElement = client.get();
System.out.println(jsonElement.execute().body());
```

This should work and write a well-parsed JSON response root element to stdout.

Comment: Thank you so so much! @fluffy . If I want to parse the data, then i can use Gson for it is that correct?

Comment: @the_star There are many ways, and Gson is one of them as it fits your needs.

Comment: But once I get the response, how am i able to get the it to json. I tried the following `        Type foundArticleType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Article>>() {
        }.getType();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(article1);
        Article[] founderArray = gson.fromJson(foundArticleType, Article[].class);` but  i see that i need to have it as a string first.

Comment: @the_star I don't know why your thinking went this way, but please re-read the answer third section code carefully, and your questions like this will be gone.